# How to create a new user in User Pool in Amazon Cognito in Golang?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-cognito

I am using the Go SDK to integrate with Amazon Cognito on my backend. I have a simple requirements: create a new user in my user pool using the SDK. I just have the user's email address. I want the password to be automatically generated for the user and an invitation email to be sent. I also want to mark the email address as verified when creating the user.

This operation can be easily performed on the AWS Console:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il4vN.png)

All the configurations are visible in the screenshot.

I have tried the following SDK methods:

1. [SignUp](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cognitoidentityprovider/#CognitoIdentityProvider.SignUp)
2. [AdminCreateUser](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/cognitoidentityprovider/#CognitoIdentityProvider.AdminCreateUser)

`SignUp` returned an error saying user sign up is not allowed for my user pool. And, `AdminCreateUser` returned an error saying "user doesn't exist".

What do I do here? I'm running out of options.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you needed to set `DesiredDeliveryMediums` as "EMAIL" in the payload.